# JComboBox program wont load

Tags: java

[image: pic1]
The first pic is with JComboBox active in the code and the program is not loading.

[image: pic2]
The second pic is with JComboBox commented out and the program is loading as it should.

Is there something wrong with my code? or is it with my specs?

Comment: Is that single line of code the *only* difference between the two?

Comment: yes, can't figure it out what is wrong with it, when the jcombobox code line is active frame wont load, but when i comment it out program loads fine, there's also no bugs.

Comment: Images of code are not helpful.  Edit your question, and copy the code into your question as text.

Answer (score 0):

May want to try something like:

```
String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "December"};
JComboBox monthsComboBox =new JComboBox(months);
monthsComboBox.setBounds(50, 50,90,20);    
frameVariableNameHere.add(monthsComboBox);        
frameVariableNameHere.add.setLayout(null);    
frameVariableNameHere.add.setSize(200,300);    
frameVariableNameHere.add.setVisible(true);
```

or try something like:

```
String[] months = new String[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "November", "December"};
JComboBox<String> months1 = new JComboBox<>(months);
```

**Additional Resources:**

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jcombobox

https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jcombobox-basic-tutorial-and-examples